# people picker custom action in app maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

During custom action in people picker field how to convert the string to a object [image: image alt text]

Answer (score 0):

Just check `valueIsRecord` checkbox

[image: Value is record]

**Note**

Looks like there is a bug in App Maker and it will not immediately change event handler's label from `string` to `Object`, but it should work OK in runtime. If you want the label be updated, just reload browser's tab.